# What to do when the OP answers his own question in comments and none answer was right?

Tags: discussion

Not so long ago I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195820/using-make-on-windows/23195965#23195965), where the OP eventually found another way to solve his problem, while the answer **could** also helps him solve it.

In this state, the question will remain unanswered, and while the answer is one way of helping the OP, it is not **what helped the OP solving his problem**.

What should we do in this kind of situation ?

Comment: Nothing. This question and similar questions are quite abundant here on meta.

Comment: In this case the whole problem seems to be based on a simple typo by the OP. There is a specific close reason for that.

Comment: Just let it be, there's nothing you can do over it. Everyone may downvote, upvote, accept anything they consider right. However, that's the point of being a community, it's not just the OP who decides what's right or wrong, I'm sure that if an answer is worthy, other users will tend to upvote it.